# Python program to create sphere coordinates not working

Tags: python, geometry, coordinates

I am trying to generate points that lies on the surface of a sphere centered on (0,0) in python.

```
# r - the radius of the sphere
def createSphere(r):
    lst = []
    for z in range(-r, r+1):

        r_ = r - abs(z)
        if r_ == 0:
            lst.append((0,0,r*np.sign(z)))
        else:
            for d in range(r_):
                lst.append((r_ * cos(d * (360/float(r_))), r_ * sin(d * 360/float(r_))), z)            )
    return lst
```

It will return a list [(x1,y1,z1),...].

This is how the result looks like: 
[image]

The surface isn't smooth, and it looks kinda like a cube with extra sharp corners.

Does anyone know whats wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You might be interested in [sphere tesselation](http://www.fho-emden.de/~hoffmann/ikos27042002.pdf) to generate your vectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [standard spherical to cartesian coordinate transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates):

```
import math
pi = math.pi
sin = math.sin
cos = math.cos

def createSphere(r, N=10):
    lst = []
    thetas = [(2*pi*i)/N for i in range(N)]
    phis = [(pi*i)/N for i in range(N)]
    for theta in thetas:
        for phi in phis:
            x = r * sin(phi) * cos(theta)
            y = r * sin(phi) * sin(theta)
            z = r * cos(phi)
            lst.append((x, y, z))
    return lst
```

---

Per the comments below: If you wish to vary the number of points depending on the height (or `phi`), you could let `thetas` depend on `phi`:

```
def createSphere(r, N=10):
    lst = []
    for phi in [(pi*i)/(N-1) for i in range(N)]:
        M = int(sin(phi)*(N-1))+1
        for theta in [(2*pi*i)/M for i in range(M)]:
            x = r * sin(phi) * cos(theta)
            y = r * sin(phi) * sin(theta)
            z = r * cos(phi)
            lst.append((x, y, z))
    return lst
```

Above, the key line is

```
M = int(sin(phi)*(N-1))+1
```

M will equal 1 when `phi` is 0 or `pi`, and it will equal N when `phi` equals `pi/2` (at the "equator"). Note that this is just one possible way to define `M`. Instead of using `sin`, you could instead define a piecewise linear function with the same boundary values, for example...

Comment: You have a typo `(x, y z)` missing comma, and the range function takes two integrers... Do you need something that takes floats?

Comment: Right now, at each height, there is N arrows, is it possible to change it so that, at height=0 (center of sphere), there is N arrows, and then as the height goes away from 0, there is less arrows, and then at the top and bottom of the sphere, there is 1 arrow going up and down.

Comment: Do you want vectors normal to the sphere? If so, call `createSphere(r)` to find the tail and `createSphere(r+d)` to find the head of the vectors.

Comment: yes I do, but I'm not sure what you mean.... your code is already getting normal vectors, but I was just looking for basically the amount of arrows at a certain height to not be a constant N at all heights.